# How do I use the repaint() method when someone clicks?

Tags: java, user-interface

Im still learning Java, I can programm simple softwares but I am completely rubbish when it comes down to creating GUIs.
I want to make a simple GUI that prints out a simple rectangle on the screen and where ever the user clicks within that GUI, the rectangle is moved to that location.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class circle extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

int x = 0;
int y = 0;


public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 25, 10);

}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
    x = m.getX();
    y = m.getY();
    repaint();


}
```

I obviously missed out on mouseEntered/Exited/Pressed/Released since that doesn't contain any code yet. What im failing to understand is that why is the rectangle not printing out where I click unless I'm using the wrong methods like repaint....

My main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Circle Prog");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    circle co = new circle();
    f.add(co);


    f.setSize(300, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `MouseListener` hasnt been registered with the panel

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public CirclePanel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 25, 10);
    }

       ...
}
```

Some notes

- Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` for custom painting in Swing and remember to call `super.paintComponent(g)`. While `paint` may work it won't take advantage of Swings optimized paint model

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) You need to add the MouseListener.  Maybe in a constructor:

```
public circle() {
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

2) You need to call `super.paint(g)`.